# SQL query converted to LINQ

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I write this SQL query using LINQ?

I tried a few ideas but can't figure it out :

```
  SELECT  id , Email
  FROM Customer
  WHERE Customer.Id IN 
  (SELECT CustPeople.PeopleID
  FROM  CustPeople    WHERE MemID = 1)
```

Table `Customer`:

```
    Id  Email        
   --------------------------
    1   johnDoe@aol.com
    12  billGates@yahoo.com
    11  charlieParker@aol.com
```

Table `CustPeople`:

```
    Id  MemID   PeopleID
    ----------------------
    1   1       11
    2   1       12
    3   4       163
```

Result :

```
    11  charlieParker@aol.com
    12  billGates@yahoo.com
```

Do I use joins? Is there some way of creating a sub query in linq?

```
   var people = from c in _custRepository.Table
                join p in _custPeopleRepository.Table on c.Id equals p.MemID
                ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contains` call on a collection will be translated into `IN` clause:

```
var people = from c in _custRepository.Table
             where _custPeopleRepository.Table
                                        .Where(x => x.MemID == 1)
                                        .Select(x => x.PeopleID)
                                        .Contains(c.Id)
             select new { c.Id, c.Email };
```

Comment: thanks Marcin, . . I'm getting 2 errors that I'm not really understanding for the .Contains part :

'System.Linq.IQueryable<Nop.Core.Domain.GiftList.CustPeople>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 
'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments
----------And this one---------:  

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Nop.Core.Domain.GiftList.CustPeople>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int>'